# Azure Data Sync + EF Automatic Migrations

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations, azure-data-sync

How does Azure Data Sync handle EF Automatic Migrations? Is there a way to specify a precondition of matching migration levels before allowing synchronization?

[This question is related, but only asks how EF Automatic Migrations handles consistency across multiple web roles with a single SQL instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023803/how-does-azure-websites-with-ef-migrations-ensure-integrity-when-updating); it doesn't involve Data Sync in the equation.

Comment: Hi!

I'm using Entity Framework Migrations in my Azure SQL and I'dont have any problem. Don't have a precondition **if your Azure Sql have one federation**.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Data Sync is ignorant of EF or any other applications. and there is no API or hooks where you can intercept and influence it's behaviour.